# How to ignore duplicate and NULL values when using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

First making connection:

```
private void connection()    
    sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCom"].ConnectionString;    
    con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
```

Then I insert records from a `.CSV` file into the SQL Server table:

```
private void InsertCSVRecords(DataTable csvdt)  
{
    connection();  

    // creating object of SqlBulkCopy    
    SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);  

    // assigning destination table name    
    objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Users";  

    // Mapping the table columns
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");  
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");  
   
    // inserting rows into database    
    con.Open();  
    objbulk.WriteToServer(csvdt);  
    con.Close();  
}
```

Extract the wanted text from CSV:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    DataTable tblcsv = new DataTable();  
    //creating columns  
    tblcsv.Columns.Add("Name");  
    tblcsv.Columns.Add("Email");  
   
    string CSVFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);  
      
    string ReadCSV = File.ReadAllText(CSVFilePath);  
    
    foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))  
    {  
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))  
        {  
            //Adding each row into datatable  
            tblcsv.Rows.Add();  
            int count = 0;  

            foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(','))  
            {  
                tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;  
                count++;  
            }  
        }    
    }  

    // Calling insert Functions  
    InsertCSVRecords(tblcsv);  
}
```

The problem is that when I use `objbulk.WriteToServer(csvdt);` this does not ignore the duplicate values...

What I have tried to apply is to use `PRIMARY KEY` when creating the table:

```
protected void CreateT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Users = "";
    string Email = "";
    string Name = "";

    connection();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = con;
  
    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + Users + "(" + Email + " varchar(255), " + Name + " varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (Email));";
            
    con.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

But the problem is that when run the code PRIMARY KEY throws exception because of duplicate values but I want `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()` to insert data from `.CSV` into the table without duplicate and NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

Either not add duplicated records to DataTable or create this DataTable with unique constraints to prevent duplicates before placing them in DataTable

Comment: DataTable with unique constraints? How to do that?

Comment: Did you try search for DataTable Constraint etc? Give it a try. Probably you till be redirected to SO in się mother place from the past 

Comment: I have used UniqeConstraints but got this error message: These columns don't currently have unique values.     UniqueConstraint custUnique = new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { tblcsv2.Columns[Name], 
                                           tblcsv2.Columns[Email] });

            
            tblcsv2.Constraints.Add(custUnique);
            
        InsertCSVRecords(tblcsv2);

Comment: If you add constraints AFTER adding data then it will not work. You need foret define DataTable limitations and after that try add rows. Those failing will indicate constraints violations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.enforceconstraints?view=net-7.0 will this sample work on your env?